# Issue Running php artisan optimize

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm having an issue with my Laravel 5.2 application. I tried to install my repository to Forge, and I kept getting an "Invalid filename provided" error that is preventing the install from completing.

To mimic this on my local machine, I changed my .env file to production mode and ran `php artisan optimize`, which is where the Forge install is getting stuck. I get the same error, and here is the output from my laravel.log file.

```
[2016-06-10 03:14:39] local.ERROR: RuntimeException: Invalid filename provided. in /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/classpreloader/classpreloader/src/ClassPreloader.php:114
Stack trace:
#0 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php(83): ClassPreloader\ClassPreloader->getCode(false, false)
#1 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php(64): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand->compileClasses()
#2 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand->fire()
#3 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(507): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(169): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#5 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(259): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(155): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(844): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(192): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(123): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /{{ APP_PATH }}/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /{{ APP_PATH }}/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 {main}
```

My `config/compile.php` file has nothing in the `files` or `providers` arrays. The scripts section of my composer.json is updated to the current version. Here is my whole composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "authorizenet/authorizenet": "^1.8",
        "inacho/php-credit-card-validator": "^1.0",
        "geoip2/geoip2": "^2.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.1",
        "pingdevelopment/usps-php-api": "@dev",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.3",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "jms/serializer": "xsd2php-dev as 0.18.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.6.1",
        "easypost/easypost-php": "^3.0"
    },
    "repositories": [{
          "type": "vcs",
          "url": "https://github.com/goetas/serializer.git"
      }],
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "goetas/xsd2php": "2.*@dev",
        "goetas/xsd-reader": "2.*@dev",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "{{ APP NAME }}\\": "app/{{ APP NAME }}"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

I'm really lost here.

Comment: did you try `php artisan optimize --force`

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the error when I run `php artisan optimize` and `php artisan optimize --force`

Answer (score 1):

I went through every dependency, and I found the culprit. Turns out it was `"authorizenet/authorizenet": "^1.8"`. They were referencing `"goetas/xsd2php": "2.*@dev"`, which has been abandoned. They are still working on a fix to integrate the new repository, but in the meantime, a hot fix was added. That dependency should be replaced with `"goetas/xsd2php": "2.0.x-dev#fdc2ab0bb3f2b3ab796ca567cf8c0f3446a7ea3a"`.